# How to do division of 2 elements belonging to GT group pbc

Tags: cryptography, division, elliptic-curve

Is the formula given in [PBC manual](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual.html) applicable for 2 elements of GT group in elliptic curve?

> ```
> void element_div(element_t n, element_t a, element_t b)
> ```
>
> Set n = a / b.

Comment: Or is it for 2 G1 or Zr elements only?

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work. GT is a multiplicative group and division is essentially a multiplication with `b` inverted.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further.